# Communication Chains Implementation

Tags: c++, oop, communication, boost-asio

I'm designing a new system that needs to support communication using several different communication protocols. I don't need to use them together, just to be able to switch between them easily. Also, sometimes protocol consist of several layers, and I would like to implement each layer separately.
I was wondering what is the best design for these kind of software - My OOP approach says I should use a base class that'll represent a layer (with read/write), and inherit from it all protocols. Also the base class should have a "next layer" property that will point to the next layer in the communication chain.
I'll need to implement a layer for each protocol (HTTP, Encryption, etc), and a "bottom" layer for each end link (RS232, TCP/IP, Bluetooth, etc)

This sounds standard. But I'm sure that there's something better. What are the existing options on the web today? I know of ASIO from the Boost libraries that implements something kinda similiar. But I haven't found anything that seems right for the job.

It's a Windows based project. I'm thinking about C++ (my native), but I'm not locked on it yet. C# is a strong option as well (my semi-native).

Comment: What makes you so sure there's something better? A layered approach is quite apropos for this problem.  Your real choice will be between inheritance and composition.  One or the other will fit better depending on your overall application architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping that there is an infrastructure out there that implements so layers so I could use something and not implement it all from scratch

Comment: Based on the limited amount of information available, I think that an interface ILayer and a sorted set of ILayer instances are all that you need. I don't see anything that would warrant a third-party library.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented such an infrastructure. https://github.com/Nitaym/Nexus   It's not bullet-proof yet, but it's very useful